# Derived category of homotopy category of R-module

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, category-theory, triangulated-categories, derived-categories

I was wondering if we construct the homotopy category of R-module is it the same as homotopy category of projective R-mod ?

In the homotopy category of projective R-mod we know that quasi-isomorphism are the same as isomorphism, and the derived category of the homotopy category is obtained by formally inverting all the quasi-isomorphism, such that they become isomorphism.

I was wondering what condition is necessarily such that the derived category of R-mod the same as the derived category of projective R-mod ?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to know whether $\textbf{K}(R)\cong \textbf{D}(R)$, i.e. whether the homotopy category of $R$-modules is equivalent to the derived category of $R$-modules?\

Comment: @Hanno I want to know if $D(R-mod) \cong K(Proj-R-mod)$.

Comment: If not I want to know under which condition the equivalence occurs.

Comment: Ok. It's very crucial to know the boundings here. Do you want all complexes, potentially unbounded to both sides?

Comment: I want to know conditions for all complexes.

Comment: @Hanno I was wondering if your gonna add an answer I am very interested to see a detailed thing for when the complexes are bounded.

Comment: The first paragraph of the question, the third paragraph of the question, and your first comment are all asking about different pairs of categories. Could you edit the question to make it clear which categories you're actually interested in?

Answer (score 2):

In the unbounded situation, the statement I know is the following:

**Proposition** [[Bökstedt–Neeman](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=CM_1993__86_2_209_0), Prop. 2.12*]**.** *Let $\mathscr{A}$ be an abelian category with enough projectives satisfying* AB4. *Then, the composite functor*
$$K(P) \hookrightarrow K(\mathscr{A}) \to D(\mathscr{A})$$
*is an equivalence of categories, where $K(P)$ is the smallest full subcategory containing the bounded above complexes of projectives that is closed under coproducts and the formation of triangles in the homotopy category $K(\mathscr{A})$.*

Bökstedt and Neeman really prove the version involving injectives, but you can dualize appropriately to get the result above. At some point I wrote up some of the relevant details in §1 of [this note](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~takumim/NeemanBalmer.pdf).

It is also probably important to remark that this category $K(P)$ consists of what are called *K-projective* complexes in the literature, which were first defined by [Spaltenstein](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=CM_1988__65_2_121_0), to whom the proposition above could also be attributed (although the result is not stated explicitly). Note that $K(P)$ is [not quite the same](https://mathoverflow.net/a/120095/33088) as the subcategory of $K(\mathscr{A})$ consisting of all complexes with projective terms.